# How to setup a callback URL for an android application to receive POST requests from an API?

Tags: android, withings

I would like to integrate a Withings smart scale into an Android app I am developing. I am following the getting started instructions in the withings developer documentation [here](http://developer.withings.com/oauth2/#). For this I need to register my app [here](https://account.withings.com/partner/add_oauth2) and it requires a "Callback URL". Here are the details Withings provides for the Callback URL:

> Partner URL called by our system to send notifications through HTTP POST requests. Make sure that your server can handle a HTTP HEAD request called to verify the validity of your url.
>
> Your URL must :
>
> - be a valid URL, provided as a URL-encoded string. Please refer to w3schools URL encoding reference to learn more about URL encoding.
> - not be greater than 255 characters.
> - neither contain an IP or 'localhost'. Only port 80 and 443 are allowed.

How do I setup a callback URL for an android app that will be able to receive POST requests?

Comment: provide some code and give more info on question

Comment: Please link directly to the documentation on Withings and/or post a copy of the documentation you are going off of.

Comment: This seems to be a Web API, not necessarily one that will work with an Android client.

Comment: Is there no way of using it within an android app then?

Comment: Looks like you need to implement a Web server to receive the callback POST request and update your database. You can then call you server from your Android app to check for updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mobile application cannot be a callback URL because it has no static address for the API server to callback to. For example, your Android IP changes when you move from a mobile network, to your home wifi, to a coffeeshop.

What you need is a server in-between the mobile app and the Auth endpoint that can securely communicate login tokens. You can find a similar flow using a service like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/mobile-login-flow)

Answer (score 6):

I am trying to do something similar and below is a solution that works fine for me. Hope this helps.

1) In Withings developer portal, register Callback URI as:

```
https://[yourdomain]/callback
```

Replace [yourdomain] with your domain, for example:

```
https://testtest.azurewebsites.net/callback
```

2) In Android Studio

- Add an Activity, for example "RedirectHereActivity"
- In strings.xml, add your domain, for example:

```html
 <string name="domain">testtest.azurewebsites.net</string>
```

- In AndroidManifest.xml, add an intent filter to the "RedirectHereActivity"

```html
<activity android:name=".RedirectHereActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="@string/domain"
            android:pathPrefix="/callback"
            android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This way, the callback redirects to this Activity together with the access code.

Comment: Can this method accept/handle the data passed with url? and also does it work for post requests too? If yes, Can you please share a snapshot of you code.